# How recover a source code of html(not generated code) angular2 RC4

Tags: typescript, angular

How to get a source code which I typed manually in my IDE using JavaScript?

NB: I'm using `angular2 rc4`.

I tried to get it using `Reflect.getMetadata` but I get errors its not working.

```
 ///<reference path="../../../node_modules/reflect-metadata/reflect-metadata.d.ts"/>"


    alert("---- " + Reflect.getMetadata('annotations', AppComponent)[0].template);
```

I get undefined in msg alert

[image]

in index.d.ts

```
/// <reference path="globals/core-js/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/jasmine/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/node/index.d.ts" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install typings for the reflect metadata library:

```
$ typings install reflect-metadata --ambient
? Found reflect-metadata typings for DefinitelyTyped. Continue? Yes
Installing reflect-metadata@~0.0.0 (DefinitelyTyped)...

reflect-metadata
└── (No dependencies)
```

This way you'll be able to use the `Reflect` object without compilation error.

**Edit**

To load the template content from a template URL:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'src/app.html'
})
export class App {
  constructor(private http:Http) {
    let templateUrl = Reflect.getMetadata('annotations', App)[0].templateUrl;
    this.http.get(templateUrl).map(res => res.text()).subscribe(template => {
      console.log('template = '+template);
    });
  }
}
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/Tk3hfba8ytsjvhCHSWSj?p=preview.

Comment: I get this error!

typings ERR! deprecated The "ambient" flag is deprecated. Please use "global" instead
(I have reflect-metadata in my package.json) it not causing any problem

Comment: Which version of typings do you use? Do you try with the global flat? ;-)

Comment: I'm not understanding very well about this but it seems I use global
I update my answer

Comment: Now it works but I get undefined value because I use templateUrl
there is any way to get content of html page of template url thanks3

Comment: Great! Pleased to hear that! Yes, you need to use the HTTP support of Angular2 but in the `map` callback, you need to use `text()` instead of `json()`.